# Per CHANGELOG, since Version 3.53.0 phaser3 is preventing `AudioContext was not allowed` warnings, but I still encounter it, how do I do?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Per the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/480df91037b408ad4d4416d73da60a45e59bac68/CHANGELOG.md), since Version 3.53.0 - Anastasia - 8th March 2021

> `SceneManager.loadComplete` will no longer try to unlock the Sound Manager, preventing `AudioContext was not allowed to start` console warnings after each Scene finishes loading.

However, each time I run a phaser3 app on Chrome 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (x86_64)

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

I still get that annoying warning.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that this is a browser "issue" (look at this link, for a chromium example: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=943258#c6)
the browser, outputs this warning, if you create an `AudioContext` without user interaction. Phaser creates an `AudioContext` on creating a Phaser Game Object `new Phaser.Game(...);`.

If you want to get rid of the Warning message, I have two different ideas, how you could do this:

**Option 1:**
Make a simple html-page with a start button/image/... and only create the `Phaser.Game` Object after a user iteraction, then there would be no Warning. *(this is "cleaner", abit of overhead)*

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#btnStart');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var game = new Phaser.Game();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<button id="btnStart"> Start </button>
```

**Option 2:**
Or you could clear the console, with `console.clear();` after creating the object. *(easy quick fix)*

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game();
console.clear();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> Just so that you know the Warning has no effect, a can be ignored.